Full screen results in entire screen of horizontal lines
After Ubuntu 24.04 upgrade, Firefox has no issues while in Chrome, every full screen in YouTube and in one other website fills the screen with green and yellow horizontal lines. Looks like:

An attempt to take a screenshot briefly returns to a frozen normal screen.
Some other programs in full screen also result in the same yellow/green striped screen: VLC player and Visual Studio Code; while others such as Stremio have no issue with full screen.
Connecting an external screen  negates the problem in all programs I checked (Chrome and VLC), full screen goes without problem both on the main and on the secondary screen. Disconnecting the external screen results in going back to the yellow/green stripes when in full screen.
I have asked about it in Chrome support.google in September, but have not received a reply.
For Chrome, I've tried:  disabling Chrome extensions, disabling hardware acceleration, clearing cache and cookies, and reinstalling Chrome; but I saw no improvement.
I've tried to figure out what GPU drivers I have for my Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2). I followed the Intel instructions from here, but reached a dead end. 'clinfo' shows number of platforms 0, and I couldn't understand why.
'Software & Updates', in the tab for 'Additional Drivers' says that I do not have any proprietary drivers drivers in use and no additional drivers (It is empty).
I did not find questions about the same problem. Did anyone else encounter a similar problem and what have they tried? I am not sure what to check, and will appreciate any help and suggestions

If you see the problem in several individual programs at once - you cant fix it there. Chrome for example. Try upgrading / reinstalling your GPU drivers.

Thank you for you response.
The problem is in more than one program, but not in all programs (Firefox and Stremio full screen works).
I've tried to figure out what GPU drivers I have for my Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2). I followed the instruction from intel from here but reached a dead end. 'clinfo' shows number of platforms 0, and I couldn't understand why.
Could I receive additional help?

If you have an intel GPU you have the latest greatest drivers with the intel kernel. So if you fiddled around with 3rd party drivers, this could very well be the cause. Intel releases all their driver code to the linux kernel - as opposed to nvidia - that don't. Again if you have problems in more than one program with the same error - the error does not lie here imho.

I do not remember ever trying to install third party drivers, so I guess I have the intel kernel. I don't know how to check.
'Software & Updates', in the tab for 'Additional Drivers' says that I do not have any proprietary drivers drivers in use and no additional drivers (It is empty)

I ran into the exact same issue on a Dell laptop my sister has also running 24.04 with Intel UHD graphics. She has poor eyesight so she had set the resolution to 1920x1080 with 125% scaling although the native display resolution is 3840x2160.
After trying a couple of boot options for the i915 driver that did not resolve the issue I simply set her resolution to the native 4k resolution and then upped the scaling to 250%.
This completely resolved the issue.

Thank you!
I have set my resolution to the maximum one, and so far it seems I do not get the striped screen in full screen mode any more

The next thing I would fix is any firmware updates for the mobo and gpu.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

Thank you for your help!
I prefer not doing that based on guesses and without knowing what the problem is.
For now, the system works and if I need full screen on a website I can use Firefox.
That said, I would like suggestions for tests or checks I can do to identify and narrow down the problem, if possible

Ah sorry - I meant to leave a comment.
